# Padrino: undefined method session for model

Tags: ruby, session, sinatra, datamapper, padrino

I am keep getting "NoMethodError at /dataset_requests/create undefined method `session' for #". DatasetRequest is a model, not controller. The problem is caused by flash and redirect methods. What might be the problem?

My controller:

```
Ims.controllers :dataset_requests do

  get :index do
    @requests = DatasetRequest.all(:account_id => current_account.id, :order => [:date_requested.desc])
    render 'dataset_requests/index'
  end

  post :create do
    @request = DatasetRequest.new(params[:dataset_request])
    @request.account_id = current_account.id
    @request.date_requested = DateTime.now

    if @request.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Request was successfully created.'
      redirect url(:dataset_requests, :index)
    else
      flash[:error] = 'Request could not be created.'
      render 'dataset_requests/index'
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I know the mistake I have made. It is a naming conflict. Never name your var "@request".